# facebook graph-api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to retrieve latest fanpage updates from facebook for an external webpage.

There seems to be two issues...

One, it seems like the access tokens expire after an hour, is there a way to get a permanent access token?

Second, I would like to get a json string of the last 10 posts by the owner of the page (posts that contain "message" fields).

If for example, I use "https://graph.facebook.com/stackexchange/posts?fields=message&limit=10", it returns lines that do not contain the message field. Is there a way to filter these?

Perhaps there is a way retrieve this using an FQL Query?

Comment: You can't get a permanent access token, that defeats the purpose of OAuth (and security in general).

Answer (score 1):

If your page does not have any restrictions, you can get this data using a permanent app access token. If you are using one of the server-side SDKs, they will get one automatically for you.

If you aren't using an SDK, or you're writing in JavaScript, the [Login as an App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/) section of the documentation walks you through this.

The access token you gain through this method will persist until you change your app secret.

If your page has age and/or country restrictions, then you need a user access token to get the data via the API. According to the TOS, you should be authenticating each user and only showing them results if they meet the restrictions the page owner has set.

Getting the last 10 posts that a page made is best done through FQL. Try this query:

```
SELECT created_time, message, attachment FROM stream WHERE 
   source_id = YOUR_PAGE_ID AND filter_key = "owner" AND message != "" LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This SQL-style query worked well, but didn't seems to return 7 results regardless of whether I include LIMIT or not. Is there graph equivalent to this?

Comment: You can't filter with the Graph API. All you can do there is get everything and filter it on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the permanent access tokens : I think you're looking for App Access Tokens. Read more : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/

Regarding your second question : From the output, check whether there is a 'message' key existing. If not exclude that entry. In PHP there is a function array_key_exists that does the thing.

Comment: This worked perfectly for obtaining the permanent key. It was a client-side application- I used a similar js function (hasOwnProperty), however I would have preferred to query the last 10 items that I wanted rather than pruning all of the posts after being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to let one of the admins of the facebook page (`$pageId`) authorize your app (`$fbAppId`):

```
<script>
    var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
    oauth_url += '?client_id=<?php echo $fbAppId; ?>';
    oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.facebook.com/pages/null/<?php echo $pageId; ?>/?sk=app_<?php echo $fbAppId; ?>');
    oauth_url += '&scope=manage_pages'

    window.top.location = oauth_url;
</script>
```

When they authorized it, you can request a lasting token with the signed request (`$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();`) you get:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' . $fbAppId . '&client_secret=' . $appSecret . '&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=' . $signedRequest['oauth_token'];
```

cURL this URL and get the resulting access_token:

```
$access_token = substr($response, strlen('access_token='));
```

Save it to your DB. With this, you can get the posts:

```
$graphUrl = '/' . $pageId . '/posts?access_token=' . $accessToken;
$posts = $this->facebook->api($graphUrl, 'GET');
```

I have no idea, how long until this access_token expires.